# Mixcloud plugin to Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins

there is SoundCloud plugin in Rhythmbox from 3.2 version.
Is there any similar plugin to Mixcloud? Or is there a way how to use this SoundCloud plugin to play music from MixCloud?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of third party Rhythmbox plugins [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Plugins/ThirdParty). At time of writing, it doesn't look like there is a Mixcloud plugin available.

I don't believe it's possible to get the Soundcloud plugin to work with Mixcloud either - their APIs are likely completely different.